# emit Qt signal from std::thread

Tags: c++, qt

1. Есть класс, отнаследованный от QThread, с переопределенным методом run() и вызовом exec() в конце метода. В данном классе определены необходимые для работы методы.
2. Есть второй класс с определенными сигналами для вызова методов первого класса. Объект данного класса планируется создавать для обеспечения интерфейса доступа к методом первого класса, находящимся в другом потоке.
3. Есть std::thread в котором создаются объекты этих классов и вызывается метод start() для первого класса. После создания объектов выполняется соединение сигналов с методами.

Суть вопроса в следующем, при выборе  ConnectionType::QueuedConnection ничего не работает, при выборе ConnectionType::DirectConnection методы первого класса начинают вызываться, но выдается предупреждение, что осуществляется доступ из другого потока. Куда смотреть? Почему не работает с ConnectionType::QueuedConnection.

```
class Cls_1 : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Cls_1();
    virtual ~Cls_1(){};

    void Method_1(const double &param);

private:
    void run();
};

Cls_1()::Cls_1()
{

}

void Cls_1::run()
{
    ...

    exec();
}

void Cls_1::Method_1(const double &param)
{
    ;
}

class Cls_2 : public QObject
{

 Q_OBJECT

 public:
    Cls_2();
    virtual ~Cls_2(){};

    void Method_1(const double &param);

 signals: 
    void SignalMethod_1(const double &param);
}

Cls_2()::Cls_2()
{

}

void Cls_2::Method_1(const double &param)
{
    emit SignalMethod_1(param);
}
```

Код создания и подключения:

```
Cls_1 *obj_1 = new Cls_1();
obj_1->start();

_sleep(10000);

Cls_2 *obj_2 = new Cls_2();

QObject::connect(obj_2, &Cls_2::SignalMethod_1, obj_1, &Cls_1::Method_1, Qt::ConnectionType::DirectConnection);

obj_2->Method_1(1);
```

Comment: Как насчет добавить минимальный пример? :)

Comment: @gil9red, ну вот как-то так.

Comment: не нужно посылать сигналы с std::thread. Используйте QThread. или не используйте сигналы.

Comment: В Вашем коде нет `std::thread`. Работать всё, по идее, должно, поэтому показывайте минимальный пример, который мы можем собрать, и на котором такое поведение воспроизводится.

Comment: KoVadim,  ixSci этот код будет работать в существующем приложении, написанном не на Qt. А объекты будут создаваться в std::thread.

Answer (score 2):

Вы создаёте `cls2` в контексте текущего потока (который `std::thread`). Чтобы этот объект был привязан к потоку `obj_1`, надо сделать одно из двух:

1. Создавать `cls2` изнутри метода `Cls_1::run()`.
2. Перепривязать созданный объект вызовом `cls2->moveToThread(obj_1);`.

Comment: да, похоже у него проблема именно в этом — типичная ошибка, неправильное использование `QThread`. Только во втором пункте должно быть `obj_1->moveToThread(obj_1);`

Comment: @Arhad Проблема решилась перемещением созданного объекта в свой же тред. Т.е. если сделать moveToThread(this), в конструкторе cls_1 то всё начинает нормально работать. Насколько я понял это потому, что в std::thread нет event loop, а сам объект привязывается именно к event loop треда владельца. Объект cls_2 остался в std::thread. Правда не знаю, насколько верен такой подход.

Comment: @DenSDS, это ужасный подход. Вы неправильно используете `QThread`. В 99% случаев наследоваться от `QThread` не нужно вообще.

Comment: @ixSci Это один из двух подходов, из официальной документации. Из данного примера смысл выбора данного подхода конечно не ясен, но он есть. Я внутри класса приемника использую QTcpSocket доступ к которому необходимо осуществлять именно из потока, где он был создан, иначе Qt начинает выдавать warnings. Этот класс работает с оборудованием, которое болезненно переносит частые подключения, да и время на операцию достаточно критично, и тратить лишнее на постоянные переподключения - не есть правильно. А приложение, для которого пишется данный модуль постоянно вызывает методы класса в разных тредах.

Comment: Поэтому было решено вынести функционал в отдельный тред и общаться через сигналы. А сам объект класса для работы с оборудованием создавать внутри треда.

Comment: @DenSDS, эта часть документации Qt написана _вредно_, за что можно поблагодарить ребят из woboq: благодаря им документация сейчас выглядит так и продолжает плодить тот код, что Вы получили. Почитайте хотя бы эту [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150274/) (я её только просмотрел, не читал, но выглядит подходящей), чтобы понять как надо писать. Кстати, там в комментариях есть ссылка на всеобъемлющее объяснение (на английском) того, как нужно писать с использованием `QThread` правильно: полезное чтиво, если хотите углубиться в эту тему. А если не хотите, просто берите пример из статьи на хабре.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [прямой запуск слота без сигнала](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod):

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(receiverObject, "slotName", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Comment: Механизм там один, не должно быть разницы.